# ffmpeg screencasting with webcam

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot, webcam, screencast

I want to use the screen view of the computer in real-time for a fake webcam. I did the video action on the bottom. But the frames like the video (2.34) are forming on top of each other. How can I solve this problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6AZRiW3hHrw

```
Load the module
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1

Find the dummy device
v4l2-ctl --list-devices

Start the virtual-webcam (change "/dev/video1" to reflect your system)
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

Comment: Why bother with the fake webcam? Why not just feed YouTube the x11grab output?

Comment: I am trying to make a software. The software will process both images and transfer images to a remote location. I can not use it separately for two of the web cams. I thought it would be easier to take a screenshot and transfer it to the other side.